# Azure Data Explorer & IoT Hub Table Mapping Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-data-explorer

recently I have been trying to get data from IoT Hub to Data Explorer along with the MXChip AZ3166. However, I am unable to map the EnqueuedTime variable onto the Data Explorer table, whereas the other variables are mapped just fine. I've inserted my code and screenshots to help me describe the issue. May I know what the issue might be? I've tried using different types such as  datetime and string for the EnqueuedTime variable, but it still did not show up in the table. Thank you.

```
 .create table TelemetryIoTHub (EnqueuedTime: datetime, Temperature: real, Humidity: real, Pressure: real, GyroX: real, GyroY: real, GyroZ: real, AccelX: real, AccelY: real, AccelZ: real, MagX: real, MagY: real, MagZ: real)

 .create table TelemetryIoTHub ingestion json mapping 'DataMapping' '[{"column":"EnqueuedTime","path":"$.enqueuedTime","datatype":"datetime"},{"column":"Humidity","path":"$.humidity","datatype":"real"},{"column":"Pressure","path":"$.pressure","datatype":"real"},{"column":"Temperature","path":"$.temperature","datatype":"real"},{"column":"AccelX","path":"$.accelX","datatype":"real"},{"column":"AccelY","path":"$.accelY","datatype":"real"},{"column":"AccelZ","path":"$.accelZ","datatype":"real"},{"column":"GyroX","path":"$.gyroX","datatype":"real"},{"column":"GyroY","path":"$.gyroY","datatype":"real"},{"column":"GyroZ","path":"$.gyroZ","datatype":"real"},{"column":"MagX","path":"$.magnetX","datatype":"real"},{"column":"MagY","path":"$.magnetY","datatype":"real"},{"column":"MagZ","path":"$.magnetZ","datatype":"real"}]'
```

[Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgvcY.png)

[Telemetry Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Tca.png)

Answer (score 1):

Updated:
You should use the system names for this column, in this case it should be $.iothub-enqueuedtime, and also enable the iothub-enqueuedtime under the Event system properties. See the example in the [ingest from IOT hub  doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-iot-hub-overview)

```
{ "column" : "enqueuedtime", "Properties":{"Path":"$.iothub-enqueuedtime"}}'
```

Comment: I have tried using $.body.enqueuedTime, but it still did not work. Do you have any other ideas on where the issue might be at?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully your question, does this fixes the issue?

Comment: Yes this fixed the issue, thank you so much. In addition to the mapping, I also had to enable the iothub-enqueuedtime under the Event system properties under the Data Connection tab.